# iOS UItextview inside UIPageViewController not scrolling

Tags: ios, uitextview, uipageviewcontroller

I'm using UIPageViewController in my app that has 3 pages. On third page, there is a UITextView but that doesn't scroll when it has text bigger than its frame size. What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set size of textview by its contentSize property

```
CGRect myFrame = self.myTextView.frame;
myFrame.size.height = self.myTextView..contentSize.height;
self.myTextView..frame = myFrame;
```

Or u can also try

```
[myTextView sizeToFit];
```

Comment: sizeToFit changes size of my UITextView which i don't want to. Setting frame according to contentSize isn't working, i've tried it in viewWillLayoutSubviews and viewDidLoad methods.

Comment: OK there was something else with my implementation, otherwise your answer is correct. Thanks.